# Unable to create AKS cluster in westeurope location

Tags: azure-container-service

Trying to setup an AKS cluster using this guide in the westeurope location but it keeps failing at this step.

When executing this command `az aks create --location westeurope --resource-group <myResourceGroup> --name <myAKSCluster> --node-count 1 --generate-ssh-keys`

I continuously get the following error message:

`Operation failed with status: 'Bad Request'. Details: The VM size of Agent is not allowed in your subscription in location 'westeurope'. Agent VM size 'Standard_DS1_v2' is available in locations: australiaeast,australiasoutheast,brazilsouth,canadacentral,canadaeast,centralindia,centralus,centraluseuap,eastasia,eastus,eastus2euap,japaneast,japanwest,koreacentral,koreasouth,northcentralus,northeurope,southcentralus,southindia,uksouth,ukwest,westcentralus,westindia,westus,westus2.`

Even when I explicitly set the VM size to a different type of VM I still get a similar error. For example:
`az aks create --location westeurope --resource-group <myResourceGroup> --name <myAKSCluster> --node-vm-size Standard_B1s --node-count 1 --generate-ssh-keys`

results in:

`Operation failed with status: 'Bad Request'. Details: The VM size of Agent is not allowed in your subscription in location 'westeurope'. Agent VM size 'Standard_B1s' is available in locations: australiaeast,australiasoutheast,brazilsouth,canadacentral,canadaeast,centralindia,centralus,centraluseuap,eastasia,eastus,eastus2euap,japaneast,japanwest,koreacentral,koreasouth,northcentralus,northeurope,southcentralus,southindia,uksouth,ukwest,westcentralus,westindia,westus,westus2.`

It looks likes creating an AKS cluster in westeurope is forbidden / not possible at all. Anybody created a cluster in this location succesfully?

Comment: Standard_B1s is not supported as AKS requires at least 2 vcpus: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/quotas-skus-regions

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem atm for westeurope, looks like a Bug in Azure AKS. The VM's can be created through "Virtual machines" but not AKS.

Here is a different thread on this topic: https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/280

Answer (score 1):

you just need to add **--node-vm-size Standard_D2s_v3** in you command. It resolved my issue.

Note: It is to be noted that you need to pass **Standard_D2s_v3** according to your region like my region WestUS supports Standard_d16ads_v5. The above command in the question will return the available vm sizes in the exception.